# Regex parsing of digits and alphabets of variable lengths and frequency

Tags: regex

I am still a newbie to regex and find it rather steep in grasping it all in one go. Hence, I reaching out to you all to understand how I can grab the first group of digits or alphabets in the following example

```
01_crop_and_animal
02_03_forestry_fishing
05_09_13_15_19_23_31_39_other_location
68201_68202_operation_of_dwellings
a_agriculture_forestry_and_hunting_01_03
b_f_secondary_production_05_43
```

Digits seems to appear multiple times, and can have length of 2 to 5. Alphabets occur once or twice. I would essentially like to see the output as:

```
01
0203
0509131519233139
6820168202
a
bf
```

Thanks for your help!
Rob

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: In a single step, you can't get `0203` from `02_03_forestry_fishing` but you can get `02_03`.

Comment: @Toto Apologies for the delay. I am working in R. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in 2 step.

- 1rst step, match the digits/letters:

```
    ^([a-z](?:_[a-z])?|\d{2,5}(?:_\d{2,5})*)(?![a-z\d])
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/uo5G1y/2)

- 2nd step, remove the underscores.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do in two steps, first select

```
^([0-9_]+|[a-z](_[a-z])?_)
```

Then, delete all the `_` from your resulting strings.

See https://regex101.com/r/jY9Y2I/1

Comment: This doesn't give the expected result.